# RegEx for match whole word in sentences - javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to work out what the right RegEx would be for finding "s***" in a series of strings, e.g:

```
match for "find s*** in s*** foobar"
match for "s***"
don't match for "s******"
don't match for "s****** foobar"
```

I'm using a match because I want to count the number of instances of matches in the sentence. I was trying "s*{3}" as a starting point, and variations on $ and \b or \B but I can't quite figure it out.

I created some tests here to try it out, if that's helpful.

https://regex101.com/r/VdLyOY/2

Comment: cant you just split the string with spaces?

Comment: You may use `/\bs\*{3}(?!\*)/g`

Comment: I am assuming you have word with four character so after fourth character you must have space so regex will be like /[s]\*{3}(?=\s)/g

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
/\bs\*{3}(?!\*)/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PEMNFT/1)

or with a positive lookahead:

```
/\bs\*{3}(?=\s|$)/g
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `\bs`: Match letter `s` after a word bounday
- `\*{3}`: Match `*` 3 times i.e. `***`
- `(?!\*)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a `*` ahead
- `(?=\s|$)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a whitespace or line end at next position

Comment: I think the positive-lookahead version works, but the negative-lookahead version matches `s***s` and should not.  I don't *think* the positive-lookahead helps vs the one I posted for this particular problem.  I like that you included the explanation!

Comment: It is unclear if `s***s` should not be matched but I added a positive lookahead version for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/\bs\*{3}\B(?!\*)/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/UQTBdh/2)

**EXPLANATION**

```
                         EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  s                        's'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \*{3}                    '*' (3 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \B                       the boundary between two word chars (\w)
                           or two non-word chars (\W)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \*                       '*'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: @JoeHildebrand `(?!\*)` fixes that.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner  `(?!\*)` fixes that.

Answer (score 0):

`/\bs\*{3}(\s|$)/g` might work depending on exactly what your criteria are.